# PHP Array, Get every 4 results and output in a loop

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to output my array results in groups of 4.

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) { ?>
<div>
    // code     
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

The above does 4, but obviously doesn't re-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than using `Mod` as the other answers show, you could use [`array_chunk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to create the groups:

```
$groups = array_chunk($original_array, 4);

foreach($groups as $group){
    echo '<div>';
    foreach($group as $item){
        echo $item;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop whole array and group you output with help of "%" operator.

```
<div>
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if (($i % 4) == 0) {
        echo "</div><div>";
    }
    echo "Element " . $array[$i]; // CODE
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop to reloop for the whole results to be printed

```
<?php while(conditions) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) { ?>
  <div>
    // code     
  </div>
<?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this that way you can jump by 4

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i = $i+4) { 
   echo $i.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: PHP Array, Get every 4 results and output in a loop

Comment: Yes, get 4 results, pop them in a div, then pop the next four into another div and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a foreach and then just throw in an extra check to output the divs.

```
$i=0;
foreach ($array as $key->$val)
{
    if($i%3==0)
    {
        echo "<div>";
    }

    // your stuff

    if($i%3==0)
    {
        echo "</div>";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

array_slice() returns the sequence of elements from the array array as specified by the offset and length parameters.

you can check out from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 0):

try this, use `nested for` loop, this will loop 4 times. You can try to integrate with your code. If

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
   for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){
      echo $a[$j++];
   }
   echo "<br/>";
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

you can try $i++, because you use ++$i in this way "for" works 3 times!

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
```